# The use of notation $D^n [y]=f(x)$ in finding a special solution of the differential equations like $y''+2y'-3y=e^{3x}$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find a special solution of the differential equation $y''+2y'-3y=e^{3x}$.

Here's my solution following the algorithem from my professor's lecture, please correct if I am wrong:

$y''+2y'-3y=e^{3x}$

Let $y^{(n)}=f(x)$ be written as $D^n [y]=f(x)$, we can express the given differential equation as

$(D^2 + 2D-3)[y]=e^{3x}$

$(D+3)(D-1)[y]=e^{3x}$

$y=\frac{1}{(D+3)(D-1)} e^{3x}$

Using the property $\frac{1}{f(D)} e^{ax}= \frac{1}{f(a)} e^{ax}$,
where $f(a)\neq0$, we have

$y=\frac{1}{(3+3)(3-1)} e^{3x}$

$y=\frac{1}{12} e^{3x}$ is a special solution to the given differential equation.

I want to understand more about the deeper concept that lies behind the algorithm shared to us.

My question is if my solution is correct, how come we can factor $D^2[y]+2D[y]-3y$ as $(D^2 + 2D-3)[y]$ and further express this as $(D+3)(D-1)[y]$ given that the notation $D^{(n)}[y]$ is the $nth$ derivative of $y$?

Comment: I believe it takes advantage of the unique property that $\dfrac{d}{dx}[e^{ax}] = ae^{ax}$. Hence, you are able to factor out "y" and get a quadratic in coeffs, but here we restrict "_special_" solutions to $N' = aN$.

Comment: See, $(D+3)(D-1)[y]$ means $(D+3)$ applied to $(D-1)[y]$ . So why don't you try and find $(D-1)[y]=\frac{dy}{dx}-y$ first and then apply $D-3$ to $\frac{dy}{dx}-y$ and see if you get back the original ODE. As for the algorithm for finding the particular integral (solution), that is done by means of trial solutions. But in the background, the theory which lets you conclude uniquess is due to Lindelof and Picard and that is what is taught in a analytic course in ODEs.

Comment: As for $\frac{1}{f(D)}$ that is not at all a fraction nor a number. That is just a notation for the inverse of the linear operator $f(D)$ on the space of twice differentiable functions. Everything has a linear algebraic justification which is being played implicitly in the background. So a better notation(though not often used) is $f(D)^{-1}$ .

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "linear algebra".

Let $Y$ be the set of infinitely-differentiable functions. We can add functions $(y_1 + y_2)(x) = y_1(x) + y_2(x)%$ and we can scale functions by a real number $(\alpha y)(x) = \alpha y(x)$ without losing any differentiability. We also have that the zero function is infinitely-differentiable. This shows us that $Y$ is a real vector space.

Consider the operator $\text Dy = y'$. The derivative of an infinitely-differentiable function is also infinitely-differentiable, so $\text D: Y\to Y$. Further, $\text D(y_1 + \alpha y_2) = (y_1 + \alpha y_2)' = y_1' + \alpha y_2'$ so $\text D$ is linear. That means $\text D$ is an endomorphism on $Y$. The identity map $\text I(y) = y$ is also such an endomorphism. We can add, scale, and multiply (compose) endomorphisms, and so they form an algebra. Important facts about this algebra are that the distributive property holds in both directions, and $Ay + By = (A+B)y$.

Now, let's look at the left-hand side of your equation. Using the above facts about endomorphisms,

$$ y'' + 2y' - 3y = \text D^2 y + 2\text D y - 3 \text I y = (\text D^2 + 2\text D - 3\text I)y = (\text D + 3\text I)(\text D - \text I)y $$

The endomorphisms $\text D + 3\text I$ and $\text D - \text I$ are not invertible. Indeed, $(\text D - \text I)^{-1}g(x)$ should be *the* solution to the first order equation $y' - y = g(x)$, which has infinitely many solutions. However, those solutions come in the form $cy_h + y_p$ for some real $c$, so we can "fake" a unique solution by forcing $c = 0$. In other words, we only care about the particular solution and not the homogeneous components. By abuse of notation, let $P(\text D)^{-1} = 1/P(\text D)$ be the map from the inhomogeneity to the particular solution for a polynomial $P$ in $\text D$.

Evaluating this in general is quite difficult, but for exponential functions, it's much easier. This is because $\text D \exp(ax) = a\exp(ax)$, so in regards to $\exp$, we have "$\text D = a$". More formally, we assume $y = k\exp(ax)$, then substitute into $P(D)y = \exp(ax)$:

$$ P(D)(k\exp(ax)) = k(P(a)\exp(ax)) = \exp(ax) \implies k = 1/P(a) $$

as long as $P(a) \neq 0$. This gives us the result, $\exp(ax)/P(D) = \exp(ax)/P(a)$. Using this result with your equation

$$ y = \exp(3x)/(3+3)(3-1) = \exp(3x)/12 $$

is the particular solution to the given equation. This doesn't include any of the homogeneous solutions, though those can be obtained in a not-dissimilar manner.